# Users left tons of .vscode-server processes on server

Tags: process

Our programming servers have tons of .vscode-server processes left by our students. Each time a student uses VSCode ssh to connect to our server, a .vscode-server process gets created. When the student disconnects later, the .vscode-server still runs on the server. Next time the same student connects again, another .vscode-server process gets created. Eventually the student exhausts their limit and can no longer connect.

My questions are:

1. "Is there a way to configure VSCode SSH so when a user closes their end, the .vscode-server gets terminated on the server" ?
2. Is there a way to configure VSCode SSH to connect to the existing .vscode-server process if there is one owned by the user?

Thank you.

James

Right now, we have to manually remove the .vscode-server processes on our eight programming servers. it's quite tedious. We are writing a script to do it but if there is an elegant way, I would like to use it.